# How to get all the custom attributes and it's description

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes

In **Magento 2**, How do I get all the attributes and it's description ?

Please provide me a solution. Anyone have any script ?

Comment: Which attributes customer, products etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for getting all custom attributes of Product.

```
protected $_attributeFactory;



public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    ....
}

public function getCustomAttributes()
    {
    $attributeList = $this->_attributeFactory->getCollection();
    $attributeList->addFieldToFilter('is_user_defined',['eq' => 1]);

    foreach($attributeList as $attribute)
    {
        echo '<pre>';print_r($attribute->getData());
    }
}
die;
```

It's working fine for me.